# Autofocus on dynamically added textboxes - html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i am adding the text boxes dynamically to the form.

following is the code:

```html
<html lang="en-US">
    
    <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
    <script>
     var counter = 0;
        var limit = 50;
    
        function addInput(divName, arrName){
             if (counter == limit)  {
                  alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
             }
             else {
                  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
           var af = "autofocus"
                  newdiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='" + arrName + "[]' required autofocus=" + af + ">";
                  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                  counter++;
             }
        }
     
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <form action="part.php" align="center" method="POST">
         <div id = "dynamicInputHolder_1">
          <b>Emotion </b><input type="text" value="" name="emotion" id="emotion" class="generatedEmotion" readonly>
          <input type="hidden" value="" name="uniqueID" id="uniqueID">
          <div id="dynamicInput_1">
           <textarea rows="5" cols="50" readonly class="floating-box">
    John arrived at Sally's house to pick her up. John and Sally were going to a fancy restaurant that evening for a dinner. John was little nervous because he was going to ask Sally to marry him.</textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="button" value="Add connecting sentences" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput_1', 'myInputs_1');">
          </div>
    
         <br>
       </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am putting in `autofocus="autofocus"`, but it works only for the first dynamic text box, for other it does not work. Any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: element.focus()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207659/5674976 for a detailed reason for autofocus not working; it only works on page load.

Use elementName.focus()

```html
<html lang="en-US">
    
    <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
    <script>
     var counter = 0;
        var limit = 50;
    
        function addInput(divName, arrName){
             if (counter == limit)  {
                  alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
             }
             else {
                  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
           var af = "autofocus"
                  newdiv.innerHTML = "<input id='my-div-"+counter+"' type='text' name='" + arrName + "[]' required autofocus=" + af + ">";
                  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
                  document.getElementById('my-div-'+counter).focus();
                  counter++;
             }
        }
     
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <form action="part.php" align="center" method="POST">
         <div id = "dynamicInputHolder_1">
          <b>Emotion </b><input type="text" value="" name="emotion" id="emotion" class="generatedEmotion" readonly>
          <input type="hidden" value="" name="uniqueID" id="uniqueID">
          <div id="dynamicInput_1">
           <textarea rows="5" cols="50" readonly class="floating-box">
    John arrived at Sally's house to pick her up. John and Sally were going to a fancy restaurant that evening for a dinner. John was little nervous because he was going to ask Sally to marry him.</textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="button" value="Add connecting sentences" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput_1', 'myInputs_1');">
          </div>
    
         <br>
       </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

> autofocus HTML5 This Boolean attribute lets you specify that a form
>   control should have input focus **when the page loads**, unless the
>   user overrides it (e.g. by typing in a different control). **Only one
>   form element** in a document can have the autofocus attribute, which
>   is a Boolean.

so you can use autofocus to focus on something (good for server side rendering)
and you need to use javascript if you want to change this after the page is laoded.

**Edit:**
see @George Campbell answer to how to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207691/6126033

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think this answer combined with @GeorgeCampbell's answer would be fantastic! It would explain why the OP's code doesn't work and also how it can be done.

Comment: I just updated my answer, but not deleting it, maybe some ppl. want to know why it is not working at the 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use just `"<input type='text' name='" + arrName + "[]' autofocus";`

And also ...

```
$(document).on(<event>, <object>, function(event) {console.log("test"});
```

Answer (score 0):

*(old post, already accepted answer, but anyways....)*

**try this.**

```
var focusDynForms = function() {
    var captureAutoFocus = function (form) {

        var el_keys = Object.keys(form.elements);
        for(var i = 0; i < el_keys.length; i++) {
            var el = form.elements[el_keys[i]];
            if (["text","password"].indexOf(el.type)>=0){
                 if (el.autofocus){
                    el.focus();
                    return;
                 }
             }
        }
    };

    var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");

    // dynamically created forms need a helping hand to find focus in life...
    forms.forEach(captureAutoFocus);
}
```

Obviously this only addreses text and password inputs, but you can customize for other types.